# creating custom css or js file server side

Tags: javascript, css, server-side

so this question is to just see what's our there or how different people would handle something like this.  I work for a company where we've started creating a more modular driven approach to our front end development.  So we have for example a table module where some HTML, some CSS and some JS belong specifically to that module.

What we'd like to do is create something like bootstrap has done here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Any thoughts on the best way to do something like this?

Thanks for any ideas or thoughts, just curious!

Comment: You need to ask a specific question that has an objectively true answer. SO is not a discussion forum, it's not appropriate for broad questions like this and requests for ideas.

Comment: Step one, what language/framework are you using server side?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can have a final file where you can append features that you want. After appending all feature needed can now download the final file with all the features you wanted inside one file.

```
<?php
  //the final file where you want to add your selected features/
  $finalFile = 'final.css';
  //the feature you wanted to add.
  $feature = 'feature1.css';
  //append the feature to the finale file.
  file_put_contents($finalFile, $feature, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

Now can use this idea using checkbox for the feature you want.

Comment: interesting.  So if someone had selected several items they wanted to acc into the css file, would you recommend going to grab actual css or sass files that hold the chunks of css and compiling them, or would this be pieces of css that are stored in a database that you're grabbing and adding into file?

Comment: You can use any, it depends on what you are comfortable with. I have not tried getting data (feature) from database but I thing it will work. Just observe if the indentations and spaces is the same if it come from database. :)